# Laravel - Return 2 views in AJAX response

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a view with 2 `@include` directives which are subviews for updating data when AJAX call is executed.
The firt `@include` is correctly updated in AJAX response but I need to return in the same call the second `@include` for updating data shown.

I'm following the approach of **onchange** event to update partial view as following, I believe the approach will be to return also the second partial view and loaded as following: `$("#dashboardindicators").html(data);`

**Controller**

```
if($request->ajax()){
                
    return view('pages.dashboard.dashboardindicators', compact('chart4_prop_null','chart4_progress','chart3_prop_null','chart3_progress',
    'chart2_prop_null','chart2_progress','chart1_prop_null','chart1_progress',
    'market_center_dropdown', 'mega_agent_dropdown', 'teams_dropdown'));

    

} else {
    return view('pages.dashboard.dashboard', compact('chart4_prop_null','chart4_progress','chart3_prop_null','chart3_progress',
                                            'chart2_prop_null','chart2_progress','chart1_prop_null','chart1_progress',
                                            'market_center_dropdown', 'mega_agent_dropdown', 'teams_dropdown'));
}
```

**JS**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    
    $('.dropdown_get').on("change", function(){

        KTApp.block("#dashboardindicators", {
                overlayColor: "#000000",
                type: "v2",
                state: "success",
                message: "Procesando..."
            }),
        
        $.ajax({
        url: "/dashboard",
        method: 'GET',
        data: {
            market_center_id: $("#kt_market_center_dropdown option:selected").val(),
            mega_agent_id: $("#kt_mega_agent_dropdown option:selected").val(),
            team_id: $("#kt_team_dropdown option:selected").val(),
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#dashboardindicators").html(data);
            setTimeout(function () {
                    KTApp.unblock("#kt_blockui_1_content")
                });
             
        }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to return 2 views in an AJAX response, you can do that with the `response()->json()` method:

```
$dashboardIndicators = view('pages.dashboard.dashboardindicators', compact(...)->render();
$dashboard = view('pages.dashboard.dashboard', compact(...)->render();

return response()->json(['dashboardIndicators' => $dashboardIndicators, 'dashboard' => $dashboard]);
```

Then, in your `success:` function, access like so:

```
$("#dashboardindicators").html(data.dashboardIndicators);
$("#dashboard").html(data.dashboard);
```

Also, make sure to use the `->render()` function to convert the view to HTML.

Comment: Thanks @Tim Lewis. That approach works, my problem is that the second view returned is a view with 2 dropdowns and it looks that context is lost because the when I select the first time a dropdown value, AJAX call is made but the second time, AJAX is not fired.

Comment: Ah, that's pretty easy to handle. Your code: `$('.dropdown_get').on('change', ...)` can be `$('body').on('change', '.dropdown_get', ...)`. This is handles cases where you needs JS to function, even if the HTML is updated. Since you're binding the event to `body > .dropdown_get`, it'll function even if the class doesn't exist/is updated later

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tin Lewis, that approach works perfect!